# scientific notation is not available in 3D axes

Tags: python, matplotlib-3d

I use the `ax.ticklabel_format(scilimits=[0,0])` to format. But it does not show the scientific notation in 3D axes, how to fix this problem?

```
from matplotlib import cbook
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.colors import LightSource
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Load and format data
dem = cbook.get_sample_data('jacksboro_fault_dem.npz', np_load=True)
z = dem['elevation']
nrows, ncols = z.shape
x = np.linspace(dem['xmin'], dem['xmax'], ncols)
y = np.linspace(dem['ymin'], dem['ymax'], nrows)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

region = np.s_[5:50, 5:50]
x, y, z = x[region], y[region], z[region]

# Set up plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='3d'))

ls = LightSource(270, 45)
# To use a custom hillshading mode, override the built-in shading and pass
# in the rgb colors of the shaded surface calculated from "shade".
rgb = ls.shade(z, cmap=cm.gist_earth, vert_exag=0.1, blend_mode='soft')
surf = ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=1, cstride=1, facecolors=rgb,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False, shade=False)

ax.ticklabel_format(scilimits=[0,0])

plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbtLH.png)

Automatically show the scientific notation in 3D plot